# Use static Apex method in Salesforce page

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

```
public class Settings
{
   public static String getMyValue() {
      return custom_object__c.getAll().values()[0].value__c;
   }
}
```

When I try and access this in a page like this...

```
{!Settings.getMyValue()}
```

...it says...

> Error: Unknown function Settings.getMyValue. Check spelling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define an attribute and a getter in the page's controller:

```
public string settingsValue;
public string getSettingsValue()
{
    return Settings.getMyValue();
}
```

you should then be able to call {!settingsValue} from the page.

I don't think you can call methods from a page that are not in the controller.

Comment: Yup, that's what I'm doing. :)